# Is there a way to display just 1 low-reorder channel from a order set that has multiple channels?

Tags: low-reorder

I have products on my site and the client would like to order them, hence why I am using low reorder. On the main page all the different products need to be displayed, each product is in a different channel and low-reorder does this fine. However for the products individual pages I'd like to use the same order but only display the one channel. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Low Reorder extends the native channel entries tag so you should just be able to use the channel parameter. I tried the following and can confirm it works.

```
{exp:low_reorder:entries set="1" channel="channel_short_name"}
    {title}<br />
{/exp:low_reorder:entries}
```